# Editing CSS to ngb-datepicker (Angular)

Tags: css, angular, datepicker, calendar

I am trying to override the look of the Datepicker from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview). I can change the attributes in the browser with my own colors, but the selectors won't work. Am I even able to access the CSS? I can't find it in any sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

you need use `encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None` to override the style

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-basic',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-basic.html',
  styles:[
    `.ngb-dp-arrow-btn
    {
      color:red;
    }
   `
  ],
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Be carefully, ViewEncapsulation.None, make that the .css override **all** the .css to the whole application (create a tag `<styles>` at first of the index.html=